# how to read each lines of a text file and convert each line to a tuple?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I try to read a text file line by line and convert each line to tuple . this is my text file data

> danial feldroy - two scoops of django

> james - python for everyone

I need to read and convert each line to a tuple
like this `("danial feldroy "," two scoops of django")` `("james "," python for everyone")`

and I have to add this tuples to a list

```
nt = open('my_file.txt').readlines()
names_title = []
for book in nt:
    a = book.replace('-',',')
    convert_to_tuple = tuple(a)
    print(a)
    #but i have to remove the white spaces as well
```

result :

```
danial feldroy , two scoops of django
```

I expect this

```
danial feldroy,two scoops of django
```

then I want to change each lines to a tuple

```
("danial feldroy","two scoops of django")
```

but whenever I use `tuple()` it doesn't work as I expected ?

and the output for tuples

```
('d','a','n','i','a','l' etc ..
```

I expected this `("danial feldroy","two scoops of django")`!

Comment: You print the _string_ that results from replacing the `-` in the line from the file with a `,`. You never print the tuple. You never append the tuple to the list. You're using the wrong way to create the tuple -- you're looking for [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)
[How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: yes , i did on my jupyter notebook , i wants to write short question to be more readable

Comment: so how to create right tuple for text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try change what inside the loop to :

```
 nt = open('my_file.txt').readlines()
 names_title = []
 for book in nt:
     data_tuple = (x.strip() for x in book.split('-'))
     print(data_tuple)
```

The problem is you are trying to cast strings to tuples which is iterable and will cast each char to a specific character of the string.
Instead using `split()` you will divide the parts you want by some character

Comment: thank you , but how to change to tuple each line after running the strip()

Comment: It is a tuple comprehension so you get it as a tuple already.... this kind of for loop...

Comment: i checked , the type is string using type()